# Passing COM objects as parameters in C#

Tags: c#, .net, com

Given the following code, can someone explain why I can pass a COM object as a value parameter but not as a reference parameter?

```
private void TestRelease()
{
    Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.ActiveWorkbook;
    ReleaseVal(workbook);       // OK
    ReleaseRef(ref workbook);   // Fail
}

private void ReleaseVal(Object obj)
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        obj = null;
    }
}

private void ReleaseRef(ref Object obj)
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        obj = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with COM objects, it's simply a rule of C#.  You cannot pass a reference type to an `out` or `ref` param unless the reference is of the same type as the parameter type.

Otherwise it would allow for unsafe scenarios like the following

```
public void Swap(ref Object value) {
  value = typeof(Object);
}

string str = "foo";
Swap(out str); // String now has an Type???
```

Now a `string` reference refers to an object who's type is `Type` which is wrong and very unsafe.