# Can I create a generalized method to release COM objects?

Tags: c#, .net, com

Given the following code, will the ReleaseCOMObj() method release the original COM object, or will it implicitly create a copy and release that?

```
private void TestRelease()
{
    Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.ActiveWorkbook;
    // do stuff
    ReleaseComObj(workbook);
}

private static void ReleaseComObj(Object obj)
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        obj = null;
    }
}
```

**Update:** Changed method to static. See [Passing COM objects as parameters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593260/passing-com-objects-as-parameters-in-c) for an explanation as to why the Object parameter cannot be `ref Object obj`.

Comment: This rarely works in practice.  Do a bit of non-trivial interop on the workbook and you'll create lots of additional hidden reference counts.  Trust the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[C# parameters are passed by reference](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html).

Therefore, it will release the original COM object, but it won't set the original variable to `null`.

To set the original variable to `null`, change it to a `ref` parameter, which passes a variable by reference.  (and call it with the `ref` keyword)

Also, by the way, the method should be `static`, since it doesn't use `this`.

Comment: "it will release the original COM object, but it won't set the original variable to null." - that's the key piece of information that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the reference to null you can use a generic method like:

```
 private static void ReleaseComObj<T>(ref T obj) where T:class  {
        if (obj != null) {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
    }
```

Although setting the reference to null isn't needed.  The COM object will be released in any case.  See the documentation for [RealeaseComObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx).  You may also want to consider calling [FinalReleaseComObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject.aspx).

Also you could create a wrapper object that implements IDisposable and use a using block to ensrue the COM object is released even if there is an exception.

```
class ComObjectCleanUp : IDisposable {

    private T obj;

    public ComObjectCleanUp(T obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if (obj != null)
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(obj);
    }
}
```

And your code becomes:

```
private void TestRelease()
{
    Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.ActiveWorkbook;
    using (var c = new ComObjectCleanUp(workbook))
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Although I will admit that isn't very pretty, especially considering the number of COM objects you will reference using Office automation, but it's an idea anyway.

Comment: That's a clever solution, but in the end I just went with a code snippet w/ shortcut:
if ($obj$ != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject($obj$); }.